# IntelliJ 14.0 does not display project structure

Tags: intellij-idea, vaadin, vaadin7

I want to convert a normal folder in my `Vaadin Project` into a web folder and when I'm trying to open the project structure with

`File -> Project Structure` but this doesn't pop the Project Structure Window. This is the IntelliJ log:

```
com/intellij/ui/TitledSeparatorWithMnemonic
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/ui/TitledSeparatorWithMnemonic
at facet.VaadinFacetConfiguration.createEditorTabs(VaadinFacetConfiguration.java:38)
at com.intellij.facet.impl.ui.FacetEditorImpl.<init>(FacetEditorImpl.java:58)
at com.intellij.facet.impl.ProjectFacetsConfigurator.getOrCreateEditor(ProjectFacetsConfigurator.java:189)
at com.intellij.facet.impl.ui.facetType.FacetTypeEditor.a(FacetTypeEditor.java:86)
at com.intellij.facet.impl.ui.facetType.FacetTypeEditor.createComponent(FacetTypeEditor.java:100)
at com.intellij.openapi.roots.ui.configuration.projectRoot.FacetTypeConfigurable.createOptionsPanel(FacetTypeConfigurable.java:54)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.NamedConfigurable.createComponent(NamedConfigurable.java:85)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.MasterDetailsComponent.updateSelection(MasterDetailsComponent.java:696)
at com.intellij.openapi.roots.ui.configuration.projectRoot.FacetStructureConfigurable.updateSelection(FacetStructureConfigurable.java:341)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.MasterDetailsComponent.setSelectedNode(MasterDetailsComponent.java:687)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.MasterDetailsComponent.updateSelectionFromTree(MasterDetailsComponent.java:262)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.MasterDetailsComponent.reset(MasterDetailsComponent.java:407)
at com.intellij.openapi.roots.ui.configuration.projectRoot.BaseStructureConfigurable.reset(BaseStructureConfigurable.java:279)
at com.intellij.openapi.roots.ui.configuration.projectRoot.FacetStructureConfigurable.reset(FacetStructureConfigurable.java:229)
at com.intellij.openapi.roots.ui.configuration.ProjectStructureConfigurable.reset(ProjectStructureConfigurable.java:371)
at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.SingleConfigurableEditor.<init>(SingleConfigurableEditor.java:66)
at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.SingleConfigurableEditor.<init>(SingleConfigurableEditor.java:89)
at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.SingleConfigurableEditor.<init>(SingleConfigurableEditor.java:104)
at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowStructureSettingsAction$1.<init>(ShowStructureSettingsAction.java:48)
at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowStructureSettingsAction.actionPerformed(ShowStructureSettingsAction.java:48)
```

Comment: I had a similar issue a few years ago when switching IJ versions. What I did at that time was to remove the `.idea` folder from the project root, and reimport the project afterwards. However, before doing that make sure to create a backup of your project.

Comment: Thanks morfic but I found that it is waay easier work with vaadin and eclipse than with intellij